# The 'if' condition not work properly in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, list, if-statement, baseadapter, listadapter

I have this code in my getView of BaseAdapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    LinearLayout mLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_item);

    if (!mList.get(position).isOperative()) {
        mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background_inactive);
    } else {
        mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background_active);
    }

    TextView mTextOne = v.findViewById(R.id.text_one);
    TextView mTextTwo = v.findViewById(R.id.text_two);

    mTextOne.setText(mList.get(position).getPropertyOne());
    mTextTwo.setText(mList.get(position).getPropertyTwo());

    return v;
}
```

In

> **if (!mList.get(position).isOperative())**

I want to do a background setting and the background was applied properly at the begin, but if I scroll, I'm losing the initial setting.

in **mList** there are objects with 3 properties (String propertyOne, propertyTwo, Boolean isOperative).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show me what is your and what's in mList ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask... What `if`condition do you mean? There are 2 if conditions in your code

Comment: @B001ᛦ There are only `2` if Condition

Comment: Dunnow why I've seen 3 of them :) @Ashish

Comment: I'm edit the question :)

Comment: What if you replace `!mList.get(position).isOperative()` to `!mList.get(position).isOperative`? I think its a property and not a method

Comment: isOperative() is getter of object with boolean property named isOperative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution by using [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling):

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        holder.layoutOperative = convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_list_item);
        holder.txtOne = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_one);
        holder.txtTwo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_two);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (mBuildingsList.get(position).isOperative()) {
        holder.layoutOperative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background_active);
    } else {
        holder.layoutOperative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background_inactive);
    }

    holder.txtOne.setText(mList.get(position).getPropertyOne());
    holder.txtTwo.setText(mList.get(position).getPropertyTwo());

    return convertView;

}
```

Thanks to all!